# Why can I submit more than one record in a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. Why can I submit more than one record in a one-to-one relationship? There are two tables, `user` and `profile`, and they have a one-to-one relationship.

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

Profile:

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I've setup the one-to-one relationship, but I can submit more than one record into table `profile` by one user account. Why is this?

Comment: It has to be `hasOne` relationship for the profile as well.

Comment: why did you use belongsTo ??

Comment: @Drudge   documentation says:https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one  ,   and, @JilsonThomas     replacing `belongsTo` with `hasOne`,the problem exists as well.

Comment: I think for one to one you should use hasOne in both models .

Comment: @Drudge  But the problem exists as well.

Comment: how are you saving the data in the db . Can you please update your question with that code ??

Comment: Assuming that your `profiles` table has a `user_id` field, your relationships are setup correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relationships are setup correctly. The only difference between a `hasOne` and a `hasMany` is that the `hasOne` will only return the first related record. There is nothing that stops you from attempting to relate multiple records, but when you retrieve the related records, you will only get one.

For example, given the below code:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->profile()->save(new Profile(['name' => 'first']));
$user->profile()->save(new Profile(['name' => 'second']));

$user->load('profile');
$echo $user->profile->name; // "first"
```

This is perfectly valid code. It will create two new profiles, and each one will have a `user_id` set to the specified user. However, when you access the related profile through `$user->profile`, it will only load one of the related profiles. If you had defined it as a `hasMany`, it would load a Collection of all the related profiles.

If you want to protect against accidentally creating multiple profiles, you need to do this in your code:

```
$user = User::first();

// only create a profile if the user doesn't have one.
// don't use isset() or empty() here; they don't work with lazy loading.
if (!$user->profile) {
    $user->profile()->save(new Profile());
}
```